# FFMPEG - Unable to parse multiple line file

Tags: ffmpeg, bash-scripting

I'm trying to parse FFmpeg lines of output files. I'm trying to make a var that reads the line one by one but everytime I do it gives me this "[NULL @ 0x7fa9cb000000] Unable to find a suitable output format for '': Invalid argument"

```
#!/bin/bash
origfolderdirectory=${PWD} # This is the original folder directory path.
origfoldername=${PWD##*/} # This is the original folder name.

# This creates a temp folder where all the temporary files will stay.
mkdir -p Temp 

# This grabs a list of all .mp4 files and puts the output into files.txt
find . -name "*.mp4" >> ./Temp/files.txt 

cd Temp

# This removes the dots from the start of every line in files.txt and outputs fileswithoutdot.txt
cat files.txt | sed 's/^..//' > fileswithoutdot.txt 

# This adds the original folder name to the start of each line in fileswithoutdot.txt and outputs to prefixfiles.txt
cat fileswithoutdot.txt | sed -e "s#^#$origfolderdirectory#g" > prefixfiles.txt 

# This adds ../Encoded. to the start of every line in prefixfiles.txt and outputs to prefixedfiles.txt
cat prefixfiles.txt | sed -e "s#$origfoldername#Encoded./$origfoldername./#" > prefixedfiles.txt 

# Reads out prefixedfiles.txt for FFMPEG.
OUTPUT="$(cat prefixedfiles.txt)"

# Backs out of Temp folder
cd ../ 

# Copies folder structure of $origfoldername to ../Encoded.
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p -- ../Encoded./$origfoldername{} \; 

# Removes temp folder from ../Encoded
rm -r ../Encoded./$origfoldername./Temp

# Do Encode
find . -name *.mp4 -exec ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -threads 10 -crf 18 "${OUTPUT}" \;
```

Example for prefixedfiles.txt

```
Test/test.mp4
Test/More Testing/test2.mp4
```

Comment: What is your actual intention? What do you expect if `find` finds more than two files? As far as I know `find` could give you the results in random order so how would you expect to know which source file is reencoded into which target file? `OUTPUT` should be just the content of the text file (you could probably just run `cat prefixedfiles.txt`). What do you expect ffmpeg to do with that input?

Comment: They're both using the same command it seems that they output the same. As with what I expect with FFmpeg I would expect it too use the text file line by line for each operation.

Comment: I left out the rest of the script because I thought it was irrelevant but the script repeats the operation for each file.

Comment: In that case please include the rest. As it is your script doesn't really make any sense. By actually running ffmpeg within the loop it would make a tiny bit of sense but you would be overriding the same file over and over again. if you look at the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) you might be headed in the right direction but I'd expect that you can't have a line break in your output argument.

Comment: Just added whole script.

Comment: That makes certain things a lot more clear. As an example we now know that you got a file with the input files and output files and that their line numbers correlate. With this information using a loop (just like the one you used for your `rr` command before) would probably be the easiest option. See also questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg). While the documentation points out that you may have a number of inputs and outputs it doesn't contain information about the formats. So using just one for each is a good idea